# How to perform multiple pandas data type changes on different columns with one function?

Tags: python, pandas

I have 41 columns in a dataframe, out of those 22 I want to change the data type to 'str' except 1 column I want to change to 'float'.

Currently, I am doing this line of code to change individual columns to the datatype str or float, now doing this to 20 other columns:

```
df.active  = df.active.astype(str)
df.total_spent = df.total_spent.astype(float)
```

How do I write a function that takes the columns I want to make into string and the one column above that I want as a float?

Let me know if you would like the list of columns, I thought it would be too much for now.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe need seelct columns by list of names or by positions and converting:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':list('abcdef'),
                   'B':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
                   'C':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
                   'D':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
                   'E':[5,3,6,9,2,4],
                   'F':list('aaabbb')})
```

If want select columns by names:

```
c = ['B', 'C']
df[c] = df[c].astype(str)
```

If want select columns by positions:

```
p = [1,2]
df.iloc[:, p] = df.iloc[:, p].astype(str)
```

---

```
print (df.dtypes)
A    object
B    object
C    object
D     int64
E     int64
F    object
dtype: object
```